# Break line in echo variable (php )

Tags: php, html

```
$msg= 'First name: '.$fname.
        'Last name: '.$lname.
        'Client mail :' .$mail.
        'Client number :' .$number.
        'Model: ' .$model.
        'present: ' .$present.
        'Descreption: ' .$descreption.
        'Payment method: ' .$payment;
```

i want when i echo $msg; to print every line in a line. 
please help me

Comment: Echo it where? HTML output or something else...

Comment: Take a look at `explode()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a predefined constant that you should use: PHP_EOL
It makes sure that appropriate line brakes are inserted based on the OS.
Simply insert it wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
echo $msg= 'First name: '.$fname.
'<br>Last name: '.$lname.
'<br>Client mail :' .$mail.
'<br>Client number :' .$number.
'<br>Model: ' .$model.
'<br>present: ' .$present.
'<br>Descreption: ' .$descreption.
'<br>Payment method: ' .$payment
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add line breaks with `\r\n` or `<br/>` depending on if it's text or HTML output

```
$msg= 'First name: '.$fname."<br/>". 
'Last name: '.$lname."<br/>".
'Client mail :'.$mail."<br/>".
'Client number :' .$number."<br/>".
'Model: ' .$model."<br/>".
'present: '.$present."<br/>".
'Descreption: ' .$descreption."<br/>".
'Payment method: ' .$payment
```

It might be easier to read if you append the next line to your variable.

```
$msg = 'First name: '.$fname."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Last name: '.$lname."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Client mail :'.$mail."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Client number :' .$number."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Model: ' .$model."<br/>";
$msg .= 'present: '.$present."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Descreption: ' .$descreption."<br/>";
$msg .= 'Payment method: ' .$payment;
echo $msg;
```